# Inadvertent base class constructor "hiding" in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, unity-game-engine

[NOTE: Code written only to show problem, not because it's inherently useful.]

Let's say I have two classes, `A` and `B`:

```
public class A {

    public const int max = 2;
    public int[] id;

    public A() {
        this.id = new int[A.max];
    }

    public A(int id) : this() {
        this.id[0] = id;
    }

    public A(int id, int id2) : this() {
        this.id[0] = id;
        this.id[1] = id2;
    }
}

public class B : A {

    public B(int[] ids) : base() {
        int x = 0;
        while ( ( x < ids.Length ) && ( x < A.max ) ) {
            this.id[x] = ids[x];
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that by creating the new constructor in `B`, I have inadvertently hidden all of the constructors that would normally be "inherited" by `B` from `A` (Indeed, I've learned that constructors aren't inherited in C#, but I'm still confused here).

For example:

```
A first = new A();  // fine

int[] x = new int[A.max-1];
B second = new B(x); // fine

B third = new B(12); // nope
```

If I remove the new constructor from `B`, then `B third = new B(12);` works just fine (in my terminology, the constructor isn't "hidden" anymore). But with the new constructor in `B`, that `A(int)` constructor isn't available to me anymore.

So is the solution **REALLY** to simply redefine **ALL** the constructors I want B to inherit from A and make them empty? Example:

```
public class B : A {

    public B(int id) : base(id) {} // adding this!

    public B(int[] ids) : base() {
        int x = 0;
        while ( ( x < ids.Length ) && ( x < A.max ) ) {
            this.id[x] = ids[x];
        }
    }
}
```

If I make that change, now `B third = new B(12);` works just fine. But it seems a little ugly that I have to redefine every constructor I want to use in the base class of a derived class, simply because I'm adding a new constructor to that derived class!

Comment: "I remove the new constructor from B, then `B third = new B(12);` works just fine" - very unlikely - you *should* be getting the similar error as there would be no one-argument constructor in `B` (as you've already noted derived class gets no constructors from base).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Doh! I'm not sure what happened there (I remember testing it before writing that line), but you're right it doesn't work either. So that does make more sense, in terms of all the constructors being "hidden", so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, derived class does not get nor exposes constructors from base class. You need to define all necessary constructors in base class (possibly calling base class' constructor).

Note: if you derived class has nothing to initialize you may want to reconsider if you really need new class.

Comment: Geez, that seems really ugly to me. Am I missing something, for why this would be enforced in C#? Just seems like me jumping through a bunch of monotonous hoops for nothing.

Comment: @EleventyOne if you want to know why something designed particular way in language try to describe design you like and see if it makes sense (i.e. in the case of constructors think about multi-layer class hierarchies and how changes in middle layer classes propagate to child classes for example). You can also ask that as separate question (prepare for it to be borderline too broad  - check rules of [programmers.se] if it better place for such question). Note that similar languages (C++/Java) have almost identical rules for constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are absolutely correct EleventyOne your example is clunky, but the problem isn't the language it is your design. I know your example isn't a real world example and as such abstract questions will produce abstract answers.

If you find yourself with many constructors on your base class chances your design is wrong. Potentially you are trying to model something in inheritance that is better suited for composition or your base class should be taking in an object instead of individual related properties, if the properties aren't related then perhaps your base class is doing too much (Single Responsibility Principle).

When it doesn't feel right chances are you have a code smell! :)